# sublist index out of bound exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Whenever I am running my xhtml. It is giving me the following exception.
The value of statusindex object is 5. I am using JQuery for lazy scrolling,so when my xhml page
getMoreStatusList calls getMoreStatusList function, it is giving me an index out of bound exception.
There are 26 status updates in the database so index out of bound exception makes no sense to me.

1) Code

```
public List<Status> getMoreStatusList() {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
            .getSession(false);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
            + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
            Status.class);
    List<Status> results = query.getResultList();
    Query query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"
            + user.getEmail() + "'", Friend.class);
    List<Friend> results1 = query1.getResultList();
    Iterator<Friend> it = results1.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String email = it.next().getFriendEmail();
        Query query2 = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='" + email
                        + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc", Status.class);
        List<Status> results2 = query2.getResultList();
        results.addAll(results2);

    }
    Collections.sort(results);
    int index = (int) session.getAttribute("statusindex");
    System.out.println(index);
    results = results.subList(index,index+5);
    session.setAttribute("statusindex", index + 5);
    return results;

}
```

2) Exception

```
Mar 02, 2013 9:31:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/FreeBird_v.6] threw exception [/getMoreStatusList.xhtml @120,43 test="#{p.videostatus!=null}" /getMoreStatusList.xhtml @120,43 test="#{p.videostatus!=null}": /getMoreStatusList.xhtml @14,60 items="#{statusBean.moreStatusList}": Error reading 'moreStatusList' on type com.bean.StatusBean] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 30
    at java.util.SubList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.RandomAccessSubList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.subList(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Vector.subList(Unknown Source)
    at com.bean.StatusBean.getMoreStatusList(StatusBean.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IndexedValueExpression.getValue(IndexedValueExpression.java:89)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:68)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstNotEqual.getValue(AstNotEqual.java:38)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:88)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:162)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:214)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:162)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:734)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message says that `toIndex` is 30. That means that `statusindex` is not 5, as you believe it is, but 25:

> ```
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 30
> ```

Side note, you should use named parameters in your queries instead of String concatenation to pass parameters. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. It will also fail if the email address happens to contain a single quote.

Comment: Ya you are right, I printed the value of index in the console and it is giving me 25, but still I don't get it how it is becoming 25, I passed 
5 as a session object by the following code `session.setAttribute("statusindex", 5);`

Comment: But you increment it each time the method is called: `session.setAttribute("statusindex", index + 5);`

Comment: But why I am getting the exception during the first call of the method.

Comment: Define "first call". Do you redeploy the app or restart your browser each time you test the method? Do you understand what the session is? If I understand what the code is used for, the index shouldn't be stored in the session, but come from the HTML page as a parameter. And you should check that the bounds are valid before calling `subList()`.

Comment: I checked the console thoroughly, I printed the value of index, it turns out the method has been called 5 times after which it is giving an exception because value of index becomes 25. I am using JQuery for lazy loading, and maybe that is what is calling the getMoreStatusList function non-stop. Would it be helpful if post the 
all the codes of my Home.xhtml page

Comment: Take some time to investigate by yourself.

Answer (score 6):

[`List.subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)'s documentation is very clear:

> Throws: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - for an illegal endpoint index value (`fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex`)

In your case, `toIndex > size`:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 30
```

Answer (score 2):

`results = results.subList(index,index+5);`

So it would do:

`results.subList(25,30);` if passed 25, hence the error.

Comment: When I am calling getMoreStatusList I am passing 5 and 10 as parameters
`results.subList(5,10)`;

Comment: No, you aren't. If you were, you wouldn't have an exception saying that `toIndex` is 30.