# IndexOutOfBoundsException issue in java arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

The line in which the error occurs is indicated. The program consists of searching for the repeated characters and saving them in a list. In that list of type "letter", the letter will be saved in char format and the counter of the letters found.

```
 ArrayList<letter> list = new ArrayList<letter>();
 String comb = "";

 comb="hhhoofdpsdshodss";

 for(int i = 1; i<comb.length(); i++){   //16
     boolean finded = false;

     for(int j=0; j < i && finded == false; j++){
         if(comb.charAt(j)==comb.charAt(i)){
             try{
                 list.get(j).upCounter();     //Error here
             }catch(Exception E){
                 System.out.println(E);
             }
             finded = true;
         }
     }

     if(finded==false){
         list.add(new letter(comb.charAt(i)));  
     }
 }
    
 for(int i = 0; i<list.size() ; i++){
     System.out.println((char)list.get(i).getLetter() + ": " + list.get(i).getCounter());
 }
```

Here is the class "letter"

```
class letter{
    private char let;
    int counter= 0;

    public letter(char character){
        let=character;
        counter++;
    }
    public int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }
    public void upCounter(){
        counter++;
    }
    public int getLetter(){
        return let;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sublist index out of bound exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176584/sublist-index-out-of-bound-exception)

Comment: keep in mind that if `finded` is not false, it will continue looping and move on the the next element in the array (even if there are no elements left) - you probably want the condition in the `for` loop to say OR (`||`) instead of AND (`&&`)

Comment: `list` has length 0 since you didn't put anything into it. Therefore, when you try to access *anything* in it, you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: if you meant to fill `list` with the characters in `comb`, then do that. And then loop through `list` instead of through `comb`, maybe.

Comment: Unless list is a must, for this kind of job i would use hashmap and merge instead. 

But if you try to acces index > list.length() then you get indexOutofBounds. Also your code has other issues. Like counting letters multiple times, With the example string, indexes 0 and 1 have same letter and finded will = true meaning nothing gets added to list. And some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you begin, `list` is empty. When you try to access elements, it will always try to access a value that is not there, but because there is no element, there will be an error. Your ArrayList must have some values in it to begin.

Comment: It will always *throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException*, not "give a value"

Comment: I am saying it will always throw IndexOutOfBoundsException *because* there is never a value there.